# Convert list of lists into a normal list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [['0.06'], ['0.54'], ['0.61']]
```

I want to convert this list into normal list like this:

```
a = [0.06, 0.54, 0.61]
```

How can I do it it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Wait, this looks like a totally different question

Comment: @pylang: I am sorry for that... The first comment looked *so* out of place, I decided to check the edits. The OP made it an entirely new question – which goes head on against SO rules.

Comment: Which rule does this violate?

Comment: I've rolled-back to the version that has existing answers.  OP: if you have a different question, please post a new one.

Comment: Wim, good call... I guess I got distracted by looking for precedents on [meta]. @pylang: this "clever" tactic is used by people trying to avoid a question ban. Theybelieve they can ask as many questions as they want, and are not interested in helping a community at large, only themselves. One related Meta discussion (there are pages full of 'em): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265301/would-it-be-ok-to-change-a-downvoted-question-into-a-completely-different-questi

Comment: @pylang: "The edits that completely alter the question are considered **vandalism**." (Even if done by the question asker.)

Comment: @wim: thanks. I will notice about this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [['0.06'], ['0.54'], ['0.61']]
>>> [float(x) for [x] in a]
[0.06, 0.54, 0.61]
```

Comment: Can you explain how `[x]` works?  I'm unfamiliar with transforming a value within a for statement.

Comment: This is binding to a `target_list` in the grammar, and is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Comment: Wow.  That is a gem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with zip() function (returns tuple):

```
list(zip(*a))[0]

Output: 
('0.06', '0.54', '0.61')
```

To get list instead of tuple (when you want to modify the list):

```
list(list(zip(*a))[0])

Output:
['0.06', '0.54', '0.61']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using a functional approach:

```
list(map(lambda x: float(x[0]), a))
# [0.06, 0.54, 0.61]
```

Using `itertools` to first merge the sublists:

```
import itertools as it


list(map(float, it.chain.from_iterable(a)))
# [0.06, 0.54, 0.61]
```

A list comprehension is arguably more elegant and clever.